# Networking for Robotic System uses internal ethernet with no router typically, but can be connected to an external router I do not have access to

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

*Note: I am a novice in networking. Also suggestions that do not require hardware redesign of the robot are preferential*

I am developing an open-source underwater robot (AUV), and my robot currently uses UDP to communicate data packets over internal ethernet wiring. There are 3 unmanaged network switches (embedded in the system), a SOC computer (Latte Panda Alpha, DJI Manifold 2, or raspberry pi 4) with 1 ethernet port and 1 wifi port, and multiple low level microcontrollers using a W5500 chip to communicate over ethernet in the robot.

To avoid issues with the enterprise networking system at my university which requires each device get 24 hour approval to connect, I can bring the robot to my home internet. There, I can communicate between all modules, the SOC, and my personal computer using UDP. I have all devices on static IPs at the moment to minimize difficulty in connecting. I do have a few concerns for this setup when releasing the robot to the community.

My preferred behavior of the system is this: When disconnected from an external router/internet, the robot communicates locally. When connected to an external router/internet (when the underwater robot is tethered), the devices continue to communicate to each other without interruption locally, and the SOC is connected to the router/internet. I would also like to be able to connect the SOC to WIFI to SSH into the device when the robot is on shore, and keep the internal devices communicating locally.

I am concerned about an external router not accepting the static IPs, or possibly changing them, and the robot losing local communication. I am also worried that an external router will block the UDP packets.

I can add some router software to the SOC, or change from UDP to a different communication protocol, or something else, but I am not well versed in the actual networking to know the best configuration for such a system. I also cannot add a full commercial router into the system as it will not fit.

In short:

1. Can i communicate among all devices locally onboard without a router? (if no, i can add router software to the SOC).
2. If I connect a router (that I have no access to), how do i keep local communication functioning?
3. If i wish the SOC to have internet over Wi-Fi, and communicate locally using ethernet, is that possible?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Pictures of outline without router and with router are below. Wifi is not always enabled or available.
[without router setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdemV.png)
[with router setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf9YJ.png)

Comment: If you are assigning the static IP address within the Operating System itself running on the SoC then a router configured say with DHCP wouldn't be able to change or even assign the device a different IP address (since the device itself is not configured to support DHCP). Are you actually having this problem that you are worried about?  You don't mention what port you are using. Most routers for instance wouldn't block common ports, even if they did, that would have to be part of your configuration to support the device on the provided network.

Comment: What OS is the SOC/SBC that needs simultaneous local and Internet communication?  On linux you can create virtual network interfaces to enable multi-homing.  The external router cannot block data that doesn't pass through it, and static IP addresses are not subject to dynamically changing (by definition).

Comment: Do any of the onboard switches (in particular, the ones where the SOC/SBC is connected and where the external ethernet port is connected) support VLAN tagging?  It may be desirable to use VLANs to ensure that internal traffic is never visible on the external network, for example to prevent IP address conflicts.

Comment: @Ramhound using port 8888 (unofficial according to wikipedia), but I only am using that due to a seperate tutorial i followed. Flexible on changing. Also, I am only concerned at this point (no issues yet). But I am a network novice so iterating through issues takes me significant time and figured asking the experts would save me time.

Comment: @BenVoigt I will look into enable multi-homing. If its what I think it is, that could be the thing I am looking for

Comment: If possible, consider using VLANs to separate the onboard communication and the external communication. You can set it so that only the external VLAN reaches the external port. Alternatively, if your SoC can have two Ethernet ports (maybe one is a USB adapter) this is really easy because it just connects to two separate networks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i communicate among all devices locally onboard without a router? (if no, i can add router software to the SOC).

Yes. A router is only required for communicating with nodes outside the local subnet.

> If I connect a router (that I have no access to), how do i keep local communication functioning?

If you use static addressing, a router won't and can't change anything about it. However, for communicating outside the local subnet you need to use the router's addressing. You could stick to the local, static addressing as well, using multiple addresses per interface, or - preferrably - multiple interfaces, one for internal communication, one for external communication (with or without a gateway/router).

> If i wish the SOC to have internet over Wi-Fi, and communicate locally using ethernet, is that possible?

Sure. As above, using a dedicated interface for external communication would be the cleaner approach - a given for Ethernet vs Wi-fi but also a good choice for both using Ethernet as well.

The main point is that a host can use multiple interfaces and an interface can use mulitple IP addresses for different purposes. If the IP stack allows, you could even use a static address for internal communication and a DHCP address for external/gateway communication on the same interface. With dual interfaces that isn't a problem anyway.

For static, non-routed addressing you should consider using link-local aka Zeroconf aka APIPA addresses from 169.254.0.0/16. Otherwise use addresses from RFC 1918 (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16).